# Dispose x Close

Tags: c#, idisposable, disposable

In overall cases, the Close method semantically just change the state of a object that can be changed again with the Open method, indefinitely.

In other hand the semantics of IDisposable.Dispose() method put the object in a state that cannot be undone.

So, why several answers about "close x dispose" and even MSDN pattern shows Close method calling Dispose ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is plenty of friction about this is the .NET framework itself.  The implementation is however consistently without surprise, a class' Close() method always calls its Dispose() method.

Logically it always means the exact same thing.  You explicitly say "I don't use this object anymore" in your code.  So of course Close() just means the exact same thing as Dispose().  They both mean the exact same thing, "I'm done using it".  So of course the implementation of these methods do the exact same thing.

Semantically it however does *not* mean the same thing.  The big dog is the *using* statement.

You, preferably, **never** call Dispose() explicitly.  The only place is should *ever* appear in your code is in your own IDisposable implementation.  Which you need to implement when your class has members that implement IDisposable themselves.  Which obliges you to implement IDisposable yourself, you simply implement it by calling the members' Dispose method.

Which is the only place you ever use it.  In any other usage, you leave it up to the *using* statement inside of a method to automatically call Dispose() for you.  With the corner-case that you *don't* want to dispose right away, you may need to keep the object around beyond the method call.  That's when you use the Close() method.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial statement:

> In overall cases, the Close method semantically just change the state of a object that can be changed again with the Open method, indefinitely.

Is false. At least, it's false in terms of major .NET Framework classes.

In my experience, it's not often safe to write `obj.Close();` followed by `obj.Open();`. *Some* classes support such behavior, but it's certainly not a hard and fast rule. I wouldn't bet that it's true in 50% of cases.

`StreamReader.Close`, calls `Dispose`. `Stream.Close` calls `Dispose`. [SqlConnection.Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) calls `Dispose`. From the `SqlConnection` remarks:

> `Close` and `Dispose` are functionally equivalent.

I'm sure that there are cases in which `Close` does not call `Dispose`, but I would not suggest betting on the idea that `Close` can be followed by `Open`.

Comment: `Close and Dispose are functionally equivalent.` -- Not quite.  `Close()` is not automatically called when a `using` block goes out of scope; `Dispose()` is.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: In the context of `SqlConnection`, which is what I quoted, they are functionally equivalent. `Close` just calls `Dispose`. If `Close` is just a call to `Dispose`, then they're functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

It's the other way around. Usually the `Dispose` method calls `Close`.

If the `Close` method of a class is implemented to call `Dispose`, then it's because closing and disposing are the same. Once you have closed it, you can't reopen it.